# Are there any extension of primes for decimal numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Mathematicians does things which seems to be impossible. *(An example would be the factorial function. Its definition was only defined for positive integers but then mathematicians gave a definition which allowed us to apply the function to any number.)*

My question is kind of same. We have defined primes using the integers but **can we extend the idea of primes for any number?** *(It will be like asking that what are the prime factors of $e$)*.

And if mathematicians have extended the idea of primes then please tell me

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997914/how-do-you-define-a-non-integer-as-even-or-odd#comment8250877_3997914

Comment: I have written an answer to the question linked by Peter, that might be helpful here. So try checking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997914/how-do-you-define-a-non-integer-as-even-or-odd#comment8250877_3997914 for a possible answer to your question.